# How to I select every 50th row in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a large dataframe which is too big for me to convert to Pandas and use df.iloc[::50,:].

I am now trying to find an alternative solution and any help would be appreciated.

My data includes title codes which I ideally need to try to balance in the sample but my idea was that by using df.orderBy('title_code') and then selecting every 50th entry I should be ok.

Tried to convert to pandas and use df.iloc[::50,:] but dataframe is too large

Comment: you could try using [pandas API on spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/index.html) that lets you use pandas style code on spark dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

window = W.orderBy('title_code')

(
    df
    .withColumn('row_number', F.row_number().over(window))
    .filter(F.col('row_number') % 50 == 0)
)
```